How to extract NaiveDate and NaiveTime values from mySQL results in Rust?
I'm interating over results from mySQL query to generate an array of JSON objects, but some data types need to be serializable.
I've tried just extract the values explicitly by setting NaiveDate and NaiveTime, but I get  this error:
Trait `FromValue` is not implemented for `NaiveDate` [E0277]

this is actually the code:
let results: Vec<Row> = conn.exec(
        &stmt,
        params! {
            "date" => date
        },
    )?;
    let mut events = Vec::new();
    // Convert the result into a String
    for row in results {
        // FIXME: retornar date e time corretamente

        let event = json!({
            "event_id": row.get::<String, _>("event_uuid").unwrap_or_default(),
            "date": row.get::<NaiveDate, _>("date").unwrap_or_default(),
            "time": row.get::<NaiveTime, _>("time").unwrap_or_default(),
        }
        );
        events.push(event)
    }


Why is this tagged c++-chrono? What database client library are you using? These are things I brought up when this question was in review. It's not clear to me why you have not addressed those questions.

Assuming these are mysql::Row objects...
mysql::Row::get requires the type implements mysql::prelude::FromValue to convert from the MySQL value to the type. The mysql crate implements this for many types, but not NativeDate nor NativeTime.
Fortunately mysql_common does implement FromValue for chrono types. Use mysql_common and turn on chrono support.
[dependencies.mysql_common]
features = ["chrono"]

